# How to replace &lt; and &gt; from the xml response in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a response that comes from server side in xml format (partial like below)

```
<list>
    <Response>
        <cfgId>903</cfgId>
        <recommendations>
            &lt;Rule&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;Env SSA_RB_RESTART&lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;category&gt;none&lt;/category&gt;
            &lt;severity&gt;warning&lt;/severity&gt;
            &lt;ruleEvalResult&gt;true&lt;/ruleEvalResult&gt;
            &lt;actionResult&gt;Setting SSA_RB_RESTART=0 will cause RuleBase corruption.Kindly unset this environment variable and
            restart the IIR server&lt;/actionResult&gt;
            &lt;/Rule&gt;
        </recommendations>
    </Response>
    <Response>
        <cfgId>903</cfgId>
        <recommendations>
            &lt;Rule&gt;
            &lt;name&gt;SSAOPTS (+Ltd) setting&lt;/name&gt;
            &lt;category&gt;none&lt;/category&gt;
            &lt;severity&gt;warning&lt;/severity&gt;
            &lt;ruleEvalResult&gt;true&lt;/ruleEvalResult&gt;
            &lt;actionResult&gt;
            Please note that it is not recommended to have SSAOPTS=+Ltd in case of the 
            Production environment.&lt;/actionResult&gt;
            &lt;/Rule&gt;
        </recommendations>
    </Response>
</list>
```

**update**

I get the main `Response` tag with `xml=$(xmldata); var resp_x = $(xml).find('Response').text();` and then I am trying to replace with below

```
resp_x = resp_x.replace(/&lt;/g,"<");
resp_x = resp_x.replace(/&gt;/g,">");
var rule_x = $(resp_x).find('name').text();
alert(rule_x);
```

but it gives me blank, please help me fetch `severity`.

**UPDATE with my answer**

```
var xmlString=xmlToString(xmldata);
                xmlString=xmlString.replace(/(&lt;)/g,"<").replace(/(&gt;)/g,">");

                xml=StringtoXML(xmlString);

 //now I can do my operations here
 $(xml).find('Response').each(function(){
   console.debug($(this).find('severity').text());
 });


function xmlToString(xmlObj) {
if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
{
   return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlObj);
}
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
    return xmlObj.xml;
}
}

function StringtoXML(text){
if (window.ActiveXObject){
  var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
  doc.async='false';
  doc.loadXML(text);
} else {
  var parser=new DOMParser();
  var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
}
return doc;
}
```

Comment: cRazy xml response. Why `Rule` `name` ... `severity` is not a tags?

Comment: I would get them to fix the *server.* That's where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're converting the returned XML to a jQuery object too early and then doing the replace wrong. Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'list.xml',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        console.debug(data);

        data = data.replace('&lt;', '<', 'gm')
                   .replace('&gt;', '>', 'gm');

        console.debug(data);

        var $severities = $(data).find('severity');

        console.debug($severities);
    }
});
```

In the `replace()`, you need both the `g` (global) and `m` (multi-line) flags. See the documentation on [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for details.

Comment: My response is a `xml Object` because when I use `alert(xmldata);` it gives me `[object]` and with `alert(xml);` it gives me `[object Object]`. What can be done in such case?

Comment: First, you should stop doing `alert()` for debugging. Use Firefox and install Firebug, or use a browser with built-in development tools and use `console.debug()` instead. I'll update my answer with a full example.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
resp_x = resp_x.replace(/(&lt;)/g,"<");
                resp_x = resp_x.replace(/(&gt;)/g,">");
                var rule_x=$(resp_x).find('name').text();
                alert(rule_x);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Next example can help you:

```
var str="&lt;Rule&gt;&lt;name&gt;Env SSA_RB_RESTART&lt;/name&gt;&lt;category&gt;none&lt;/category&gt;&lt;severity&gt;warning&lt;/severity&gt;&lt;ruleEvalResult&gt;true&lt;/ruleEvalResult&gt;&lt;actionResult&gt;Setting SSA_RB_RESTART=0 will cause RuleBase corruption.Kindly unset this environment variable and restart the IIR server&lt;/actionResult&gt;"

str=str.replace(/&lt;|&gt;/g,function(s){return s==="&lt;"?"<":">"});
// str now is: "<Rule><name>Env SSA_RB_RESTART</name><category>none</category><severity>warning</severity><ruleEvalResult>true</ruleEvalResult><actionResult>Setting SSA_RB_RESTART=0 will cause RuleBase corruption.Kindly unset this environment variable and restart the IIR server</actionResult>"
```

**Update:** 
next code does not need to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` for getting `severity`:

```
var response="<list><Response><cfgId>903</cfgId><recommendations>&lt;Rule&gt;&lt;name&gt;Env SSA_RB_RESTART&lt;/name&gt;&lt;category&gt;none&lt;/category&gt;&lt;severity&gt;warning&lt;/severity&gt;&lt;ruleEvalResult&gt;true&lt;/ruleEvalResult&gt;&lt;actionResult&gt;Setting SSA_RB_RESTART=0 will cause RuleBase corruption.Kindly unset this environment variable and restart the IIR server&lt;/actionResult&gt; &lt;/Rule&gt;</recommendations></Response><Response><cfgId>903</cfgId><recommendations>&lt;Rule&gt;&lt;name&gt;SSAOPTS (+Ltd) setting&lt;/name&gt;&lt;category&gt;none&lt;/category&gt;&lt;severity&gt;warning&lt;/severity&gt;&lt;ruleEvalResult&gt;true&lt;/ruleEvalResult&gt;&lt;actionResult&gt; Please note that it is not recommended to have SSAOPTS=+Ltd in case of the  Production environment.&lt;/actionResult&gt;&lt;/Rule&gt;</recommendations></Response></list>";

var recs=$(response).find("recommendations");

for(var i=0;i<recs.length;i++) {
  var xml=$("<recommendations>"+$(recs[i]).text()+"</recommendations>");
  alert(xml.find("severity").text());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZpYac/

Comment: I think my reponse is in xml Object format and so it cannot use `replace` see my update in the question. when i use `alert(xmldata);` it gives me `[object]` and with `alert(xml);` it gives me `[object Object]`

Comment: @Abhishek Simon: I cannot test this, but try to replace in my second example code line `var recs=$(response).find("recommendations");` with line `var recs=$(xmldata).find("recommendations");` or with line `var recs=$($(xmldata)).find("recommendations");`. `for` loop must remain unchanged.

Comment: Hi @Andrew: I managed to find a solution.. see my updated question for my solution. thanks for your answer